# Rellenar un objeto con valores de un loop - JS

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, objeto

Estoy realizando un ejercicio donde debo recorrer una cadena de texto y guardar en un objeto todas las letras y cuantas veces se repiten.

```
let frase= "hello world"
let letras ={}

Por consola mostrar: {h:1, e:1, l:2, o:2 ..etc}
```

He intentando algo asi: Si la propiedad existe, sumar 1.  Si no existe, crearla e inicializarla con valor 1.

```js
let par = "hello world"
let counts = {};

for(let i=0; i<par.length;i++){
    if(counts.par[i]){
        counts.par[i]=par[i] + 1
    }else{
        counts.par[i]=1
    }
 }   


console.log(counts);
```

Pero no logro llegar a nada. Tambien intente usar push() pero no me sirvio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya casi lo tenías, sólo que no estabas guardando los valores en la llave correcta.

`counts.par` accede a la propiedad `par` del objeto `counts`. Propiedad que en ningún momento se definió (por lo que es `undefined`).

`counts.par[i]` accede al elemento `i` de la propiedad `par` del objeto `counts`, pero sucede que `counts.par` nunca se definió, por eso te sale el error

```
TypeError: counts.par is undefined
```

Lo correcto sería ir llenando el objeto `counts` con tuplas `(k, v)` donde `k` (key) corresponda a una letra y `v` (value) al número de ocurrencias de esa misma letra dentro de la cadena de texto.

Para eso nada más vamos a cambiar un poco tu código por lo siguiente:

```js
let par = "hello world"
let counts = {};

let letter; // La letra va a ser la llave k
for (let i = 0; i < par.length; i++) {
    letter = par[i];

    // si el objeto ya tiene un valor asociado a la llave k
    // entonces simplemente incrementar ese valor
    // puesto que se acaba de encontrar una nueva coincidencia
    if (counts[letter] /*!== undefined*/)
        counts[letter] += 1;
    // si el objeto no tiene ningún valor asociado a k (counts[letter] === undefined)
    // entonces hay que asociar un valor, en este caso 1 pues si no tiene asociado un valor quiere decir que la llave no se encontró previamente
    // ergo, esta es la primera vez que se encuentra la llave
    else
        counts[letter] = 1;
}


console.log(counts);
```

Y listo. Los comentarios del código creo que son suficientes.

Una forma de hacerlo más reducido el código ya que estamos con javascript es la siguiente

```js
let par = "hello world"
let counts = {};

for (const c of par)
    counts[c] = (counts[c] || 0) + 1;

console.log(counts);
```

Como puedes ver es el mismo resultado. Esta otra opción te la dejo para que investigues más y aprendas más.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Nose si estoy haciendo buen uso de los comentarios, pero me quedo una duda respecto a tu solucion. Decir: " counts.par[i] o counts.par " no es lo mismo que decir " counts[letter] ?? , porque entiendo que en las 2 formas estoy intentado ver el valor en el objeto. Como el objeto esta vacio, no entiendo porque counts[letter] no marca error si el objeto no existe, pero si marca error con counts.par o counts.par[i]

Comment: Está bien, sí puedes usar los comentarios así, no hay problema.
`counts.par` accede a la propiedad `par` de `counts`, la cual no está definida. Tienes una variable que se llama `par` pero esa es otra onda, no tiene nada que ver con `count`.
Por otro lado, en efecto `counts[letter]` no está definido la primera vez que se accede a la propiedad, de hecho por eso escribí `if (counts[letter] /*!== undefined*/)` pues como es `undefined`, al evaluar su "verdadez" en el if, retorna falso, así funciona javascript, puedes checar más [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Comment: Y no marca error porque precisamente en el if se evalúa si la propiedad no está definida, le asigna un valor, y si sí está definida le suma un valor. Entonces en cualquier caso `counts[letter]` termina siendo un valor definido.
Tal vez sea un poco confuso pues `counts['a']` y `counts.a` acceden a la misma propiedad pero con diferente sintaxis. Si te interesa, investiga sobre hashmaps para saber más sobre cómo se hace eso internamente.